# Is there any Sequelize driver for the Snowflake cloud database?

Tags: sequelize.js, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can't seem to find anything related on Github or NPM. Is anybody aware of any library/driver for Sequelize with Snowflake?

Comment: No there is not, and I see that you requested a driver on github 